# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'locationController'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'locationController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'locationRepository'; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'locationRepository' defined in
> com.abunyc.location.repository.LocationRepository defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for
> method public abstract java.util.List
> com.abunyc.location.repository.LocationRepository.findTypeAndCount()!

### ReportUtil.java

```
package com.abunyc.location.util;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

public interface ReportUtil {
    
    void generatePieChart(String path, List<Object[]> data );

}
```

### ReportUtilImpl.java

```
package com.abunyc.location.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class ReportUtilImpl implements ReportUtil {

    @Override
    public void generatePieChart(String path, List<Object[]> data) {
        DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

        for (Object[] objects : data) {
            dataset.setValue(objects[0].toString(), new Double(objects[1].toString()));
        }
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Location Type Report", dataset);

        try {
            ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG(new File(path + "/pieChart.jpeg"), chart, 300, 300);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

### LocationReportory.java##

```
package com.abunyc.location.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.abunyc.location.entities.Location;

/**
 * @author Abu
 */

@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Integer> {

    @Query("select type, count(type) from location_tbl group by type")
    public List<Object[]> findTypeAndCount();

}
```

### LocationController.java

```
package com.abunyc.location.controller;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.abunyc.location.entities.Location;
import com.abunyc.location.repository.LocationRepository;
import com.abunyc.location.service.LocationService;
import com.abunyc.location.util.EmailUtil;
import com.abunyc.location.util.ReportUtil;

/**
 * @author Abu
 */


@Controller
public class LocationController {

    @Autowired
    LocationRepository locationRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    LocationService locationService;
    
    @Autowired
    EmailUtil emailUtil;
    
    @Autowired
    ReportUtil reportUtil;
    
    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @RequestMapping("/showCreate")
    public String showCreate() {
        return "createLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveLoc", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveLocation(@ModelAttribute("location") Location location, ModelMap modelMap) {

        Location locationSaved = locationService.createLocation(location);
        String msg = "Location Saved with id " + locationSaved.getId();
        modelMap.addAttribute("successMsg", msg);
        //Email calls to send email.
        emailUtil.sendEmail("codeexample7@gmail.com", "Location Saved",
                "Location Saved successfully and success response was returned to the calling page");

        return "createLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/displayLocation")
    public String displayLocation(ModelMap modelMap) {
        List<Location> locations = locationService.getAllLocation();
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", locations);

        return "displayLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/deleteLocation")
    public String deleteLocation(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap) {
        Location location = new Location();
        location.setId(id);
        locationService.deleteLocation(location);
        // Reloading with all remaining datas
        List<Location> locations = locationService.getAllLocation();
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", locations);
        return "displayLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showUpdate")
    public String showUpdateLocation(@RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap modelMap) {
        Optional<Location> location = locationService.getLocationById(id);
        if (location.isPresent()) {
            Location locationUpdate = location.get();
            modelMap.addAttribute("location", locationUpdate);
        }
        return "updateLocation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/updateLoc")
    public String updateLocation(@ModelAttribute("location") Location location, ModelMap modelMap) {
        locationService.updateLocation(location);
        List<Location> aLllocation = locationService.getAllLocation();
        modelMap.addAttribute("locations", aLllocation);
        return "displayLocation";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/generateReport")
    public String generateReport() {
        List<Object[]> data = locationRepository.findTypeAndCount();
        String path = servletContext.getRealPath("/");
        reportUtil.generatePieChart(path, data);
        return "report";
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: `@Query` takes, by default` a JPQL, you wrote SQL so that won't validate. Add `nativeQuery=true` to the `@Query`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks, this really helped.